# Trip summary map, using Android's GPS

Tags: android, maps, gps

I am looking for an Android application that would allow me to generate a trip summary. At the beginning of a trip, I would indicate in the application that the trip has started, and at the end of the trip, I would indicate in the application that the trip has ended.

The trip summary should contain as many following fields as possible:

- start time
- end time
- number of kilometers
- driving/running/walking time (i.e., end time - start time - total pause time)
- the itinerary, e.g.:

  [image]

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: That's what most of the [Tracking apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking) do. Some let you even manually set "waypoints" (so you can mark important/interesting points during your trip), some even support adding photos or notes to such waypoints. Some like *Traccar* can also log right to your own server, so you could use that to "track your fleet" ;)

Comment: [My lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php) should always be the first place to look when you're after an Android app :) Especially made for that (well, originally mainly to cover the off-topic "is there an app" questions on Android.SE ;)

Answer (score 4):

OsmAnd can do it with its [Trip recording](http://osmand.net/features?id=trip-recording-plugin) plugin.
It records your track in the GPX format.

[image: Start GPX logging]

The GPX format is a standard format that is understood by Google Earth and most other map visualization tools.

Of course, you can also visualize it in OsmAnd itself:

[image: GPX OsmAnd view]

Manual page about this feature: http://osmand.net/features?id=trip-recording-plugin
As explained at the bottom of that page, you can have your route exported automatically to a Google Spreadsheet.

Each recorded point has a timestamp.